# Correct way to do multiple updates on a MongoDB database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have to receive an array of Objects and update each one of those, by their `_id`, in my MongoDB database.

I had one method that would insert one Object whenever I made an HTTP PUT, like this:

```
router.post('/bet', function(req, res){
  Bet.update(req.body)
    .then(dados => res.status(201).jsonp({dados: dados}))
    .catch(e => res.status(500).jsonp({error: 'erro'}))
})
```

Where `update()` is defined as:

```
module.exports.update = function(d){
    return Bet.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: d._id}, d, {new: true})
}
```

This works just fine whenever I need to update a single Bet, but to be able to update several, I created this:

```
router.put('/bets', function(req, res){
  req.body.forEach((obj) =>{
    Bet.update(obj)
    .then(dados => res.status(201).jsonp({dados: dados}))
    .catch(e => res.status(500).jsonp({error: e}))
  })
})
```

Is this correct? I'm having a lot of problems, that I honestly think are coming from doing a lot of different requests at the same time, but I'd like to start by guaranteeing that this first step is done properly.

Comment: Not quite sure if it applies to your use case, but MongoDB (Starting with version 3.2) provides a bulk update function see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/

Answer (score 0):

No, this is likely not the correct way. You are sending a response to the client the moment a single update is done.

I'd add a `updateMany` method like so:

```js
module.exports.updateMany = function(arr){
    return Promise.all(arr.map(d => Bet.findByIdAndUpdate(d._id, d, {new: true})))
}
```

The method uses [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create an array of Promises, that resolve once the update is done and then uses [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to give the ability to wait for all promises to be done.

It resolves once all updates are done, or rejects when any update fails.

*(Note: you don't have to specify a query object like `{__id:id}` for [`findByIdAndUpdate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate))*

You can then call that from your bets route:

```js
router.put('/bets', function(req, res){
  Bet.updateMany(req.body)
    .then(promiseArray => res.status(201).jsonp({dados: promiseArray}))
    .catch(e => res.status(500).jsonp({error: e}))
})
```